# Vscode seems to be changing directory when running a python script

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I seem to be having a vscode related issue. I am doing the open() function but no matter what I ask it to do it gives me a directory error. The file that I want the python script to interact with is in the same folder so it should work but when I do "import os" and "os.getcwd()" the directory it says I am in is Desktop. (the script and file are both in the "/Desktop/Python/File Handling"  directory)

It seems the script is stuck at the Desktop directory when I try to run it from vscode. If I run it by doing python3 "name of script" command in the kali linux terminal it works fine and if I check my directory again with os.getcwd() it says the correct one (/Desktop/Python/File Handling).

So I believe it's something with vscode as it literally just randomly happened one day. Yesterday my scripts were working fine and now all the ones I run from vscode, that are supposed to interact with the files in their respective folders, don't work. The vscode terminal gives me this code and as you can see it does the cd command at the start, which I believe might be the issue for why it always looks at files in the Desktop directory but I do not know how to make it stop doing that.

```
$  cd /home/kali/Desktop ; /usr/bin/env /bin/python /home/kali/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.18.2/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher 41017 -- /home/kali/Desktop/Python/File\ Handling/File\ Handling\ 2.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/Python/File Handling/File Handling 2.py", line 3, in <module>
    f = open("apple.jpeg", "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'apple.jpeg'
```

Lastly, I know about the os.chdir(r"/home/kali/Desktop/Python/File Handling") function and it fixes the issue but I do not want to have to write this command at the top of every script that is supposed to interact with the files in the folder it is in by default and because this issue just randomly came up out of nowhere the next day I opened vscode and ran my script from yesterday (without changing any code or vscode settings.)

P.S. I am using a VM as well if that helps.

Comment: finding the real reason might be best, otherwise maybe append os.getcwd() and image "apple.jpeg" in the open command and double check whether image exists

Comment: best not to use spaces in file names

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by vscode using workspace as root folder.

This will lead to a problem. When you use the `os.getcwd()` method in the deep directory of the workspace, you will still get the workspace directory.

You can open your settings and search **Python > Terminal: Execute In File Dir** then check it.

[image]

You can also use debug mode and add the following to your **launch.json**:

```
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```